# Disabled ipv6, but the setting doesn't persist after sleep

Tags: fedora, sleep, sysctl

I added these lines to a `.conf` file in the directory `/etc/sysctl.d`

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

I then do `sudo systemctl restart systemd-sysctl`

So far so good, as I can verify, e.g.
`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo/disable_ipv6` returns `1`
and I can see that ipv6 addresses are not assigned in output of `ip address`

But, if I put my computer to sleep, the setting does not persist (unless I repeat the above `sudo systemctl restart systemd-sysctl`). I am running Fedora 32. I thought that this setting should persist. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
sysctl -p
```

or for bulletproof ipv6 disable - add grub.conf line ipv6.disable=1 :

```
# cat /etc/default/grub
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1 crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```

create new grub conf:

```
# grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

and reboot:

```
# reboot
```

Comment: `sysctl -p` doesn't seem to work for me. (I'm not sure why - I thought it worked before but led to the same issue). Thanks for suggesting the grub way, but i was really hoping for something that doesn't require a reboot

Comment: well you may be hitting some service or configuration that has some IPv6 "dependency". It can be for example ::1 IPv6 localhost in /etc/hosts or some postfix configuration that binds to ::1. It can be DHCPv6 that tries to give you an IPv6 lease. That's why I suggested grub approach since I have it tested and no service will bind to IPv6 after reboot. Alternatively write a small cron that will remove any IPv6 addresses from your network interfaces. since you mention putting computer to sleep - I was uder impression that it's not an enterprise production system that cannot be restarted :)

Comment: Yes, I could reboot, but if possible I prefer to figure out the underlying issue rather than workaround it.

Comment: I guess than you just need to poke around your system and find out what is adding IPv6 address back to your interface. BTW disabling IPv6 via grub.conf is perfectly reasonable solution and not a workaround.